# Capture XML from HTTP Post C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, http-post

So I have started to work on a webhooks implementation of DocuSign. I need to accept the XML in a Web API(C#) from a HTTP post(docusign connect) and then send that data to SQL Server.The main problem is that the XML has numerous children and I am not sure how to map that to a Model. I have looked tirelessly for a solution to accept the XML in the Post controller and then send it to SQL table, but have not found anything that works. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the XML

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
<EnvelopeStatus>
<RecipientStatuses>
<RecipientStatus>
<Type>Signer</Type>
<Email>user@user.com</Email>
<UserName>test user</UserName>
<RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
<Sent>2018-03-05T10:44:06.443</Sent>
<Delivered>2018-03-05T10:45:22.443</Delivered>
<Signed>2018-03-05T10:45:24.413</Signed>
<DeclineReason/>
<Status>Completed</Status>
<RecipientIPAddress>00.00.00.00</RecipientIPAddress>
<RecipientId>aa923fgf2-e59d-45df-8447-8e55437b6cf7</RecipientId>
</RecipientStatus>
</RecipientStatuses>
<TimeGenerated>2018-03-05T10:45:42.6635679</TimeGenerated>
<EnvelopeID>3034gfdfd3-e6c3-4dsg6-af18-252f8fdsf3b5</EnvelopeID>
<Subject>Testing Webhooks DocuSign</Subject>
<Created>2018-03-05T10:42:59.24</Created>
<Sent>2018-03-05T10:45:25.617</Sent>
</EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>

using System.Web.Http;

namespace DocuSignAPI.Controllers
{
    public class DocuSignEnvelopeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]  Models.EnvelopeStatus envelope, Models.RecipientStatus status, Models.RecipientStatuses statuses, Models.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation info)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you don't want to just put it in an `xml` datatype column of the database? If you want a model, copy the xml, go to Visual Studio in a blank class file and choose Edit, paste special, paste xml as classes, then clean up the inane data types it sets.

Comment: thanks, I did try that and you are right there is a lot of clean up required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate your Model class from [Model Generator](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)
and then you can continue on your path.

DocuSignEnvelopeInformation is your root object all incoming data will be wrapped inside that Check out Code

```
namespace DocuSignAPI.Controllers
{
    public class DocuSignEnvelopeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(Models.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation data)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have the model now thanks to that awesome model generator. Do I then declare multiple parameters with each class in the Post method like my code above shows now?

Comment: @FrankCastle616 Hope Updated answer will help you.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. My final question (I promise), How does the controller handle the XML such as reading and then sending it to a DB. Sorry again for being a C# noob

Comment: @FrankCastle616 it is broad question but i'll try to answer it shortly let say you have 5 columns in sql database and 5 properties in your model, so you'll write insert into query for that sql table and in param you'll pass property of model. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I lied, not my final question (lol). Yeah I understand your comment, I guess my question focuses more on how do I get the values of each XML node (stream reader?) in the controller and assign it to the correct model property?

Comment: You can try POSTMAN https://www.getpostman.com/ to call your API and know how your API will behave when any web hook hits your API.

Comment: I am currently using that and Fiddler to send post requests to the API. However the 'data' parameter from the POST method is showing null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166421/discussion-between-mihir-dave-and-frankcastle616).

Comment: Fixed issue by adding User-Agent: Fiddler in post header. Thanks again for the help, it helped out greatly